# ARC custom UItextView not released

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, uitextview

I have a custom `UITextView`, in my xib I drop a `UITextView` then change its class into my CustomTextView.

I declare in my interface the text view like so:

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet CustomTextView *textViewInputDictee;
```

I post some code of my custom text view because Stackoverflow won't let me post this question but it is useless I think:

```
-(BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender
{
    if (action == @selector(defineSelection:))
    {
        return NO;
    }
    else if (action == @selector(translateSelection:))
    {
        return NO;
    }
    else if (action == @selector(copy:))
    {
        return NO;
    }
    else if (action == @selector(paste:))
    {
        return NO;
    }
    else if (action == @selector(cut:))
    {
        return NO;
    }
    else {
        return  NO; 
    }

    return [super canPerformAction:action withSender:sender];
}
```

If my text view become first responder when I pop the controller the custom text view is not released (4 mo).

I do not understand why and how can I force it to be released.

Comment: Is the text view in a stand-alone xib? or is it in the view controller xib and put as subview of the main view controller view?

Comment: i do not understand, i think it is the second part, i have set customTextView.h and .m then drag a UItextView on my controller Xib and then change its type (class) in the detail inspector.

Comment: If your text view has been added inside the view controller's view hierarchy, it will be retained by that view and will be finally released when the view controller view is released. The "view" property of a UIViewController is in fact declared as "retain". You can check if your UITextView dealloc is called only when the view is finally released. From iOS6 freeing a UIView hierarchy is hard and you must do that by explicitly setting the view controller view to nil (and eventually ensure the view is no longer in the window hierarchy).

Comment: Thank you viggio This is i think the problem i'll give a try.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to force it to be released, if you are using ARC you shouldn't worry about it.

Use Instruments or analyze your code using Command+Shift+B and check for leaks. If there ins't any, don't worry.

Comment: i need to worry, because my app at this point is 200MB memory, on iPad mini it is to closed from memory overload... but thanks

Comment: Then use instruments to check where the memory is being leaked. I doubt your memory is 200Mb because of a view controller.

Comment: i do not understand very well the instruments, when i comment my code where the textview become the first responder and i pop back the memory is released and come back to its initial point.

Comment: I do recommend you to check this guide: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: Trust me i did. I have learned how to mark generation . . . I can identify where my memory leak...

Comment: Sorry for not being able to solve it, but your question is very wide and the only thing I can do is try to point you in the right direction.

Comment: thank you Antonio, just let me tell you what i have seen. My App had huge memory usage, especially on non retina device, when i poped my controller the memory never went down, everybody told me to check instrument, i have learned, no leak, but no solution. And then i learned that huge UIImageView are not released on iOS. The problem is not to use instrument the problem is that some objects are not released even if they do no have any reference left on it.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to remove your custom `UITextView` and check if the memory is going down after that, if it does then you have a problem with the custom `UITextView`, if not the problem is elsewhere. Also when you use instruments make sure your zombies are disabled, instruments will give you a false result if your zombies are enabled. Also I suppose you are using some delegates for your `UITextView`, make sure that they are `assign` not `strong`.

Comment: I do not use delegate, i'm sure it is the custom text view, the memory goes down if i removed it. Zombies are disabled (default). Thanks